# How do I reference a variable in a Perl substitution script?

Tags: perl, substitution

I am writing a Perl script to change all URLs within several files in one directory from camel case to lowercase.

e.g. from

```
   <a href="FooBar.html">
```

to

```
   <a href="foobar.html">
```

This test substitution correctly renames all URLs to foobartest.html as expected:

```
   s/^<a href=\"(.*?)\"/<a href=\"foobartest.html\"/g
```

But I am having difficulty in referencing the actual filename via the variable $1. An example of what I am trying:

```
   s/^<a href=\"(.*?)\"/<a href=\"\L$1\"/g
```

This substitution merely changes the link to . What am I missing?
You can probably tell I'm fairly new to Perl, and so any guidance would be much appreciated.

---

Full script for reading files within a directory and substituting (writing it as a one-liner does not work either, despite other substitutions working via one line):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

    chdir("/var/www/html/twiki_html") or die "$!";
    opendir (DIR, ".") or die "$!";
    my @files = grep {/.*?\.html/} readdir DIR;
    close DIR;
        {
        local @ARGV = @files;
        while(<>){
            s/^<a href=\""(.*?)\"/<a href=\"\L$1\"/g;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In the second example, you are missing the parentheses around `.*?`, and that's why you don't have `$1`.

Comment: Is the \"" a transcription error, or is that actually in the code you're running?

Comment: In your regex `/.*?\.html/` in your grep, the beginning `.*?` is quite useless. It means "If the filename begins with anything, or nothing" -- in other words, it matches all possible strings. `/\.html/` would do the same, and `/\.html*$/i` would probably be better.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, you have no output method specified. This script would not change anything at all, unless possibly if run with `perl -pi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one-liner:

```
perl -pwe 's/(?<=<a href=")([^"]+)(?=")/\L$1/' *.html
```

It will not change anything, just display the changes. So, when you are satisfied it works, you can add `-i` to the options to make changes to the files. Be aware that changes are irreversible. Use `-i.bak` to keep backups. E.g.:

```
perl -i.bak -pwe 's/(?<=<a href=")([^"]+)(?=")/\L$1/' *.html
```

Comment: Thank you for this - and thank you for your above comments also. It seems that I was complicating things for myself unnecessarily and not fully understanding what my code was doing. I'll be doing some homework!

Comment: Would you explain to me, my error concerning having no output method in my script (in OP) please? I am having difficulty knowing where I have gone wrong - one-liners work fine for me, however.

Comment: Well, what you are doing there is just opening the html-files for reading, and you change the links, but never print them, nor change any files. So all the changes you do exist only in temporary variables, which are discarded during execution. Adding `print;` after your substitution might have fixed your script, at least to the point where you would print your changes to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. So I guess that any problems must be in the code that you're not showing us.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.010;

$_ = '<a href="FooBar.html">';

s/^<a href=\"(.*?)\"/<a href=\"\L$1\"/g;

say;
```

Running that gives:

```
$ ./html_test
<a href="foobar.html">
```

Comment: You're right - I think I am missing something vital, as I cannot get it to work for my files. I have tried both a script and one-liner, and neither work. I shall post up my script in the original question.